# Getting NaN values when I extract pixel values of a raster using a point shapefile in R

Tags: raster, r, point, value-extraction

I try to extract pixel values at defined points in a raster file in R, using a point shape file.

With some raster files it works perfectly, with others it returns 'NaN' values for all extracted points. With the LULC Layer (Land Use and Land Cover) of the NASA it works [https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/lulc-human-modification-terrestrial-systems/data-download], but with others like the DRYAD Human Footprint map [https://datadryad.org/stash/dataset/doi:10.5061/dryad.052q5] it doesn't and returns only 'NaN' values.

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(terra)
library(sf)

points <- st_read("./data_eurocam/GIS/check_points/check_points_new_for_gee.shp", crs = 4326) # EPSG 4326 = WGS 84
raster <- terra::rast("./data_metadata/lulc/lulc.tif")
 
extracted_values <- terra::extract(raster, vect(points))
```

Does anyone know what's my mistake? Do I need to set a crs when loading the raster file as well?

Comment: The two objects need to have the same CRS. Hard to tell because you've not shown us anything about the data. What are they? What are their extents and coordinate systems? And you shouldn't have to specify the `crs` argument to `st_read` if the shapefile has its `.prj` file present and correct... Thanks for the links to the data, but that still hundreds of gigabytes of download which you could save us by showing us summary info of the data objects.

Comment: Hi again and thanks already for your help! I really thought I checked the crs of the data, but appearently I conused the files and the crs of the DRYAD data was 'World_Mollweide'.  The extraction of the pixel values workes now perfectly, so thanks for the hint!

Comment: I used this code for the projection: ```raster_pr = project(raster_dryad, "EPSG:4326", method = "bilinear")```

The pixel values measure the human impact on the landscape in values in a continous scale from 0 to 1. Therefore it is ok to use the 'bilinear' method, right? Thanks for your help, the field of spacial data analysis is pretty new to me.

Comment: Yes, bilinear is usually pretty good for continuous data.

Comment: perfect, thank you (: